# Mini SQL support in Dotnet

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, database

There is Mini SQL DBMS that can be found in below link.

https://hughestech.com.au/products/msql/

I want to connect this with my Dotnet 4.5 Project.
Do anyone has idea on where i can get the dlls to connect & perform CRUD operations on thie DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

i don't even know this kind of database "mSql".

For a .NET environment you need a .NET driver. But they only provide a "Perl" driver. The forum seems pretty empty, if you encounter a problem, it will be really hard to resolve it. So you can use "Perl" or change database type.

If your goal is to have a tiny DataBase have a look to **sqlite** that is a bit more popular and used.

Comment: @Anup Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?